# Trigger background service at a specific time in Android

Tags: android, service

I want to start a service in background everyday at a particular time. I am on android 2.2. please suggest me a sample code.

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want the [Android Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.

And [here is a tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) for your viewing pleasure.