# how to implement system Alarm Clock in my applications?

Tags: android, android-alarms

How do implement an alarm clock in my application. i want to implement an alarm that is similar to system alarm. 
or
Any Intent that i can use to set system alarm from my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [Android Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the future.

And [here is a tutorial](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) for your viewing pleasure.

Also, just so you know, [the question right before the one you just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274141/trigger-background-service-at-a-specific-time-in-android) answers the exact same problem. You probably could have searched for this solution.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - Yes.  Signal to Noise ratio is important.  I typed in his question and the auto-search-assist pointed me to a solution if i just included Android...

Comment: hi, Robert what i want to implement is set the system alarm clock from my application using the SET_ALARM, SET_MESSAGE variables. this will save lots of work of mine as i dont have to create my custom alarm clock.