# Call a function at particular time in android

Tags: android

In my android app there is a button to logout.I need the app to logout at 4 pm.Please anybody help me to know how I can make this by calling the logout function at a particular time in device

Comment: dupicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274141/trigger-background-service-at-a-specific-time-in-android) question

Answer (score 0):

To do a task at some particular time, you need to implement `AlarmManager`.

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

You can implement Alarm Manager, and invoke an **IntentService** that logs out the user as per your need